# logrotate succeeds when manually run as root, but fails with "Read-only file system" when run by logrotate.service

Tags: 20.04, systemd, logrotate

I have a (formerly working) logrotate setup for OpenResty that I took from a previous Ubuntu 18.04 installation. Yet the logrotate.service fails with this error now ...

```
error: error renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.60.zst
to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.61.zst: Read-only file system
```

... and I have difficulties understanding why. The new machines are running Ubuntu 20.04, but I don't see why that should make a difference in this case.

First, here is the config:

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/custom-openresty

/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log
{
  daily
  rotate 60
  maxsize 1G
  missingok
  notifempty
  compress
  compresscmd /usr/bin/zstd
  uncompresscmd /usr/bin/unzstd
  compressoptions -9 --long -T1
  compressext .zst
  delaycompress
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    test ! -f /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/nginx.pid || kill -USR1 `cat /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
 endscript
}
```

`/etc/logrotate.conf` is unchanged and looks like this:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the adm group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root adm

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
#dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

Here is the state of my files (I would expect to get `access.log.1` after logrotate ran):

```
$ ls -alhg /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/
total 10G
drwxr-xr-x  2 root 4.0K Sep 16 20:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root 4.0K Sep 16 19:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  10G Sep 16 19:56 access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root 5.5K Sep 16 19:56 error.log
```

However, the logrotate.service fails with this error:

```
~$ systemctl status logrotate.service 
● logrotate.service - Rotate log files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-09-16 20:11:32 UTC; 4min 32s ago
TriggeredBy: ● logrotate.timer
       Docs: man:logrotate(8)
             man:logrotate.conf(5)
    Process: 27403 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 27403 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

$ sudo journalctl --unit logrotate.service

Sep 16 20:11:32 fetcher-scheduler systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Sep 16 20:11:32 fetcher-scheduler logrotate[27403]: error: error renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.60.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.61.zst: Read-only file system
Sep 16 20:11:32 fetcher-scheduler systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 20:11:32 fetcher-scheduler systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 20:11:32 fetcher-scheduler systemd[1]: Failed to start Rotate log files.
```

When I run it (without systemd) in debug mode as root, I get the following output:

```
# logrotate -v -d /etc/logrotate.d/custom-openresty

reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/custom-openresty
compress_prog is now /usr/bin/zstd
uncompress_prog is now /usr/bin/unzstd
compress_options is now  -9 --long -T1
compress_ext is now .zst
Reading state from file: /var/lib/logrotate/status
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state
Creating new state
...
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log
 after 1 days (60 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, log files >= 1073741824 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
considering log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log
  Now: 2020-09-16 20:24
  Last rotated at 2020-09-16 20:11
  log needs rotating
considering log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log
  Now: 2020-09-16 20:24
  Last rotated at 2020-09-16 19:00
  log does not need rotating (log has been rotated at 2020-9-16 19:0, that is not day ago yet)
rotating log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log, log->rotateCount is 60
dateext suffix '-20200916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1 does not exist
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.60.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.61.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 60), 
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.59.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.60.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 59), 
...
/logs/access.log.3.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.2.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.0.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 0), 
log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.61.zst doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1
running postrotate script
running script with arg /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log
: "
    test ! -f /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/nginx.pid || kill -USR1 `cat /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`
"
```

To me, everything looks normal. If I run it, it also works:

```
# logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/custom-openresty
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/custom-openresty
compress_prog is now /usr/bin/zstd
uncompress_prog is now /usr/bin/unzstd
compress_options is now  -9 --long -T1
compress_ext is now .zst
Reading state from file: /var/lib/logrotate/status
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state
...
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log
 after 1 days (60 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, log files >= 1073741824 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
considering log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log
  Now: 2020-09-16 20:26
  Last rotated at 2020-09-16 20:11
  log needs rotating
considering log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log
  Now: 2020-09-16 20:26
  Last rotated at 2020-09-16 19:00
  log does not need rotating (log has been rotated at 2020-9-16 19:0, that is not day ago yet)
rotating log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log, log->rotateCount is 60
dateext suffix '-20200916'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1 does not exist
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.60.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.61.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 60), 
old log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.60.zst does not exist
...
old log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.2.zst does not exist
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.2.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1.zst does not exist
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.0.zst to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1.zst (rotatecount 60, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.0.zst does not exist
log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.61.zst doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log to /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.1
running postrotate script
```

No error and in the end `access.log.1` is created as expected:

```
# ls -algh /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/
total 10G
drwxr-xr-x  2 root 4.0K Sep 16 20:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root 4.0K Sep 16 19:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  10G Sep 16 19:56 access.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root 5.5K Sep 16 19:56 error.log
```

Note that it said ...

```
log /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log.61.zst
doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
```

... instead of `error renaming ... Read-only file system` (as `logrotate.service` does)

**Why does it work when running manually as root, but fails when it is executed by the logrotate.service?**

I did not make any changes to `logrotate.service`. For completeness, here is the unit file:

```
$ systemctl cat logrotate.service
# /lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service
[Unit]
Description=Rotate log files
Documentation=man:logrotate(8) man:logrotate.conf(5)
ConditionACPower=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf

# performance options
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
IOSchedulingPriority=7

# hardening options
#  details: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
#  no ProtectHome for userdir logs
#  no PrivateNetwork for mail deliviery
#  no ProtectKernelTunables for working SELinux with systemd older than 235
#  no MemoryDenyWriteExecute for gzip on i686
PrivateDevices=true
PrivateTmp=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectSystem=full
RestrictRealtime=true
```

Now I'm running out of options. Any help in troubleshooting the problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, I found it. The logrotate file is not the problem.

Instead, it is caused by the hardening features in the systemd unit file. After I disabled the `ProtectSystem=full` hardening options, it worked. The reason is that logrotate has to operate on the `/usr` directory in my case, which is readonly if the option is enabled.

From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) on `ProtectSystem=`

> Takes a boolean argument or the special values "full" or "strict". **If true, mounts the /usr and the boot loader directories (/boot and /efi) read-only for processes invoked by this unit.** If set to "full", the /etc directory is mounted read-only, too. If set to "strict" the entire file system hierarchy is mounted read-only, except for the API file system subtrees /dev, /proc and /sys (protect these directories using PrivateDevices=, ProtectKernelTunables=, ProtectControlGroups=). This setting ensures that any modification of the vendor-supplied operating system (and optionally its configuration, and local mounts) is prohibited for the service. It is recommended to enable this setting for all long-running services, unless they are involved with system updates or need to modify the operating system in other ways. If this option is used, ReadWritePaths= may be used to exclude specific directories from being made read-only. This setting is implied if DynamicUser= is set. This setting cannot ensure protection in all cases. In general it has the same limitations as ReadOnlyPaths=, see below. Defaults to off.

To fix it properly, I added now the following line to `/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service`:

```
ReadWritePaths=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs
```

Then `ProtectSystem=full` will mount everything as readonly except the directory where the logs are. Now, the readonly error is gone:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start logrotate
(completed successfully without output)
```

---

I assume, I never hit the problem on Ubuntu 18.04 because the hardening options were not yet the defaults. Ubuntu 20.04 has it now, but I don't know in what Ubuntu release they were first introduced.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I was totally clueless as suddenly log rotation stopped and never raised any sort of error. Ultimately we hit a disk full problem to realize that the log file had grown to tens of GBs.. !

Comment: Thanks, I was facing exactly the same problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Nice find to the same problem i was seeing.
Editing nginx.conf to log to different directory (eg. the common /var/log/nginx) is an alternative that also works.